# Why does it take a long time to get a response from the retrofit in some cases?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Retrofit @get request sometimes
It takes a long time to get the answer (10-15 sec.).
I am only getting string data. on average 1-2 kb.

No problem when I send request from postman

What do you think is the problem?

**RetrofitService.class**;

```
 private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

private val call = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(Constants.LINK)
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build().create(ApiEndpointRXJava::class.java)


fun getRetrofit(query: String, auth: String, queryList: List<String>): Single<List<ListModel>> {
    return  call.getRetrofit(query, auth, queryList)
}
```

**Interface;**

```
    @GET(".../.../...")
    fun getRetrofit(
        @Query("query") query: String,
        @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
        @Query("queryList") queryList: List<String>
    ): Single<List<ListModel>>
```

**ViewModel.class;**

```
fun getRetrofit(query: String, auth: String, queryList: List<String>) {
    errorData.value = false

    disposable.add(
        retrofit
            .getRetrofit(query, auth, queryList)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<List<ListModel>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: List<ListModel>) {
                    v.value = t
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.value = true
                }
            })
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If sometimes it works fast sometimes with delay - it looks like issue is not in your codebase.
Maybe the issue on the server side or in your network connection.
To check this case you can use Fiddler or Charles to sniff your application traffic. And if response in the sniffing program will have the same time then issue is not related to your codebase.

Comment: he clearly said he was using Postman and did not get the same outcome. I am currently having the same problem, and this is only happening in Android.  iOS and Postman take < 300ms, as in android, possibly (retrofit | okhttp) 3000ms

Comment: Yes, I've seen a line about postman. But when he makes request from the phone, metadata can be different and maybe it make some impact on the way, how it processed on the server side.
The purpose of using Fiddler is to understand where is the issue:
1) Is it related to server side and long response time
2) is it related to client side.(Maybe some issue in config or in the network lib)

Comment: Currently, I have iOS and Postman working great.  Android I must say simulator is way slow for obvious reasons, but in-device a pixel 4 turned out to process the request faster than a oppo, so hardware plays a clear role in this behavior.